# EXEC parameters from a SELECT

Tags: sql-server, select, exec

I have a SP like this with dozens of parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[traxs_FileMaint_ProductRecord_Insert]

    @param_1 varchar(100) = NULL,
    @param_2 varchar(20) = NULL,
    /* List goes on */
    @param_n tinyint

AS
    /* Some irrelevant stuff */
```

And I'm building another SP which uses the first one:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[traxs_WebsiteInterfaceProduct_Save_Complete]

    @parameter_1 varchar(100),
    @parameter_2 varchar(50),
    /* List goes on */
    @parameter_n, tinyint

AS

    EXEC traxs_FileMaint_ProductRecord_Insert 
    SELECT  
        @param_1 = @parameter_1,
        @param_2 = S.product,
        @param_3 = S.id,
        /* List goes on */
        @param_n = @parameter_7
    FROM
        TOP 1 traxs_temp..__website_interface_selected S
    WHERE S.selected = 1
```

I know I could `DECLARE` variables and stock values from `SELECT` statement in these variables, but I really have dozens of parameters, and I think it could be better to use parameters directly from `SELECT` if possible.

As stated in the example, some parameters of the `EXEC` will be issued from `SELECT` statement, and some will be parameters of the parent SP.

I hope this makes any sense.

Comment: Nope you cannot do this, you will need to populate variables separately and then pass the variables to the procedure.

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't want to read sir ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @sql = 'EXEC traxs_FileMaint_ProductRecord_Insert '
              + '@parameter_1,' +  S.product + ',' + S.id
FROM   tablename S
WHERE  S.selected = 1

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Note : There should only one row from select else last row will be considered and if `Id` is of numeric type then you may have to convert it

Example :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Newp] (@a VARCHAR(50))
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT 1
  END

GO

DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @sql = 'exec newp' +  a from (select 'a' a) sub

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql
```

Comment: aren't you missing the declaration of parameters for sp_executesql ? and how this will work? can you explain please?

Comment: @M.Ali - This is not the exact procedure this is just a query which can be used inside the procedure.

Comment: for parameters like `@parameter_1` , `@parameter_2`... `@parameter_7` you will need to declare parameters for sp_executesql and pass values for these parameters, mind you the dynamic sql you are building doesn't have access to parameters declared outside of its scope.

Comment: @M.Ali - Please check the example

Comment: have a look at this SQL Fiddle, what you are trying to do can be done by doing something like this ... [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41875)

Comment: @M.Ali What else you need. Its just a simple example to fetch data directly from table.

Comment: The reason OP asked this question was he/she wants to avoid declaring all the variables for the procedure variables and passing values one by one, with your suggested approach , op will have to declare the variables anyway , see my sql fiddle for a somewhat complete version of your suggested method.

Comment: @M.Ali First time while checked Fiddle is empty. Now only i can see your query. What am suggesting is you don't need those variables also while executing the procedure directly pass the values updated my answer check now.

Comment: The simple example you are showing it will work but OP has this procedure (with lots of variables) being called from inside of another procedure, for that you will have to do what I have suggested in my sql fiddle. If you still cant get it, I rest my case.

Comment: look at this SQL Fiddle and try to call Oldp from inside of Newp with your suggested methond [`SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41876)

Comment: I tried Dynamic SQL and I thought it was what I needed. But I can't just write `EXEC Sp_executesql @sql`. I have to specify every parameter: `EXEC Sp_executesql @sql, N'@param_1 [Datatype],@param_2 [Datatype]',@param_1,@param_2`. It's like declaring every parameters without Dynamic SQL.